# Expressing a certain expression as a given variable

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Now $\dfrac{x}{x^2+x+1}=a$ is known, I want to express the $\dfrac{x^2}{x^4+x^2+1}$ in the forms of a, how should I do it?

The answer is $\dfrac{a^2}{1-2a}$, and there is a limitation of $-1\leq a \leq \dfrac{1}{3}$, of course.

Comment: Another function `Eliminate`: `Eliminate[{y == x^2/(x^4 + x^2 + 1),x/(x^2 + x + 1) == a},x]` gives `a^2 + 2 a y == y`.

Comment: @lilyric Thanks. Then Solve[a^2 + 2 a y == y, {y}, Reals] will give the form I want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can solve `y` and eliminate `x`.

```
Solve[{y == x^2/(x^4 + x^2 + 1), 
   x/(x^2 + x + 1) == a}, {y}, {x}] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

Comment: It throws a Solve::fulldim error which instructs me to use Reduce, while the result is {{}}.

Comment: @ThomasPeng `Clear[x, y, a];
Solve[{y == x^2/(x^4 + x^2 + 1), x/(x^2 + x + 1) == a}, 
  y, {x}] // Simplify`

Comment: @ThomasPeng `Clear[x, y, a];
Solve[{y == x^2/(x^4 + x^2 + 1), x/(x^2 + x + 1) == a}, y, {x}, 
  Method -> Reduce] // Simplify`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I forgot to clear the variables.